# Eslint(no-unused-vars) warning when using map and assigning the element to a new value

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I have an array of booleans. Something like:

```
let array = [true, false, true, false];
```

I would like to map over the array and set all to true or all to false like so:

```
array = array.map(e => (e = true))
```

OR

```
array = array.map(e => (e = false))
```

This works, but throws the eslint warning `'e' is assigned a value but never used.eslint(no-unused-vars)`. Does anyone know why that would be? It appears that `e` is being used. I can get rid of the warning by throwing in a ternary, but I really don't need it:

```
array.map(e => (e ? true : true))
```

Also this works and removes the warning:

```
this.expanded = this.expanded.map(e => {
  e = true;
  return e;
});
```

I would much rather just use the one liners above as they work and seem valid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to set them all to `true` or `false` you need just

```
array = array.map(() => true);
```

or

```
array = array.map(() => false);
```

Alternatively:

```
array.fill(true); // or false
```

Assigning to the parameter will have no effect on the array elements. The parameter passed to the `.map()` callback is a **copy** of the array element, not any sort of reference to it (which is basically not possible in JavaScript). You *could* take advantage of the fact that the callback is also passed the index, but if you're looking for brevity that seems counter-productive.

The ESLint error is telling you that the assignment `e = true` is pointless.